# Call TDataSet.Locate in one line

Tags: c++, c++builder

In RAD Studio wiki you can find documentation on [using `TDataSet.Locate` method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Using_Locate).

Following **C++** snippet comes from there:

```
TLocateOptions Opts;
Opts.Clear();
Opts << loPartialKey;
Variant locvalues[2];
locvalues[0] = Variant("Sight Diver");
locvalues[1] = Variant("P");
CustTable->Locate("Company;Contact", VarArrayOf(locvalues, 1), Opts);
```

I'd like to do this call to `Locate` **all in one line**, as you can do in Delphi. Something like this or even simpler:

```
CustTable->Locate("Company;Contact", VarArrayOf(new Variant[2]{Variant("Sight Diver"), Variant("P")}, 1), TLocateOptions() << loPartialKey );
```

Compiler says `E2121 Function call missing )`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comments, the problem is the second parameter, and specifically the open array that `VarArrayOf` receives.

According to the documentation, the [`OPENARRAY`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Open_Arrays#OPENARRAY_macro) macro could be helpful. You'd call `VarArrayOf` like this:

```
VarArrayOf(OPENARRAY(Variant, ("Sight Diver", "P")))
```

So the call to `Locate` will become:

```
CustTable->Locate("Company;Contact", 
                  VarArrayOf(OPENARRAY(Variant, ("Sight Diver", "P"))), 
                  TLocateOptions() << loPartialKey );
```

Comment: There is also `ARRAYOFCONST`. And take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635085/how-to-translate-array-of-param-to-c

Comment: I knew of `ARRAYOFCONST`, it is for `TVarRec`... but didn't know of `OPENARRAY`... great @David!!